# UIActivityViewController, How assign names to activity items

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdata, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have some NSData that I can successfully add to an email using UIActivityViewController, as below:

```
    NSData *pDFdada = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray* dataToShare = @[pDFdada];
    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =  [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems: dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
```

Right now the pdf is shared, but using the generic name "Attachment-1". I'd like to give it a custom name like "myNewFile.pdf". Is this possible?